# How to persist TestExternalities via impl_benchmark_test_suite testing?

Tags: benchmarking, testing

I set up a state via

```
impl ExtBuilder {
 pub fn build(self) -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
  let mut t = system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<TestRuntime>().unwrap();
  let mut ext = sp_io::TestExternalities::new(t);
  ext.execute_with(|| 
      System::set_block_number(1));
      ThirdPartyModule::createAsset { ... }
  ext
 }
}
```

In the "normal" unit tests, I call `Externalities::build().execute_with(|| {...})` to access the store.

Now I want to do benchmark testing via `impl_benchmark_test_suite!` and I pass the storage as the second parameter:

`impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, Externalities::build() , Test,);`. However, the store doesn't contain the same information as with the Unit tests, and `createAsset` doesn't get triggered or at least, it is not part of the store. I wonder how I would "register" this module or this content into my store for the benchmark tests?

Comment: How are you running the benchmarks? Do the tests work `cargo t -p your-pallet --features runtime-benchmarks`? There is a difference between executing the benchmarks and the testing that `impl_benchmark_test_suite` does. Would you mind sharing the code? You can probably even put a panic in there and it will not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should rely on `Externalities::build()` to do the environment setup for your benchmarks, because it will not be called when you run your benchmarks (opposed to running benchmark test suite). AFAIK people usually use separate setup-helper functions for benchmarks. You can have a look a [this file](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1399afdcd8ab4d7fad149c96f9cadcaf04b94f86/frame/child-bounties/src/benchmarking.rs). There's `setup_bounty`, `setup_child_bounty`, `activate_bounty`, etc. I think that's the way to go.